# How to create a ONNX File?

Tags: neural-network, onnx

How to create an ONNX file manually? I mean without using the frameworks like PyTorch, caffe2, e.t.c, can we(binary encode maybe) create an onnx file, if we know the network details in prior like # of nodes, types of nodes, their connections, e.t.c?

Comment: As the [tag:onnx] tag and its [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/onnx/info) say, ONNX is an *open format*. "How to create an ONNX file manually" is exactly described by the ONNX specification, and is how all the implementations of ONNX readers and writers were created in the first place. You can also read the various implementations of the readers/writers and see how they work.

Comment: And in all those specifications it is described the ways to export a model to onnx format from various frameworks and nothing like encoding into the onnx format.

Comment: https://github.com/onnx/onnx#learn-about-the-onnx-spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!! We can use onnx.helper class inside onnx library to create a model and save it in onnx format.